# Dependency Injection in Class Library(.NET Standard 5 ) and Missing Startup.cs

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, .net-standard

I want to use dependency injection in class library build on .NET Standard 5. Also the class library dont have the startup.cs file so i can't inject my dependencies.

Is there anything i am missing here?

Kindly advise.

Comment: First, clearly identify what you're trying to work with. There is *no such thing* as .NET Standard 5. Also, dependency injection is usually the responsibility of the "host" application, not something class libraries need to/should concern themselves with.

Comment: Some libraries provide extension methods that the "host" application can call to have the library register itself with the DI container spun up by the application.

Comment: There is a big difference between a class library that is part of a solution and a class library that is shipped independently (possibly through NuGet). In case the class library is part of a (single) solution, the answer is that you place the registrations inside the [Composition Root](https://freecontent.manning.com/dependency-injection-in-net-2nd-edition-understanding-the-composition-root/). If the library, however, is a separate deployable, you should follow the practice of [DI-friendly libraries](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/).

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to write an extension method for `IServiceCollection` that registers your dependencies. Something like:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddServices(this IServiceCollection services)
    {  
        return services
            .AddTransient<IService1, Service1>()
            .AddTransient<IService2, Service2>();
    }
}
```

It would be the responsibility of the application consuming your library to call this method to register the dependencies.

Comment: And/or extensions to `IApplicationBuilder`